# Failed MySQL insert with no error, binding values in execute, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert data from an array into MySQL in PHP. I have been working on this for a long time and could use some help debugging. I am not getting any errors which is making it hard for me to find the problem. Any help I could get with this would be appreciated.

There are more than two items in the $productConfigArray, I only included a sample.

Here is the code:

```
 function insertBatch($productConfigArray) 
{
    try {

        $insertStatement = 'INSERT INTO productconfigTEST (productid, partid, currency, fobid, fobpostalcode, pricetype) VALUES';

        foreach ($productConfigArray as $index => $row) {
            $productId = $row['0'];        
            $partId = $row['1'];        
            $currency = $row['2'];
            $fobId = $row['3'];
            $fobPostalCode = $row['4'];
            $priceType = $row['5'];
            
            $insertStatement .= ' (:productId' . $index .', :partId' . $index .', :currency' . $index .', :fobId' . $index .', :fobPostalCode' . $index .', :priceType' . $index .')';
            
            $insertParams['productId' . $index] = $productId;
            $insertParams['partId' . $index] = $partId;
            $insertParams['currency' . $index] = $currency;
            $insertParams['fobId' . $index] = $fobId;
            $insertParams['fobPostalCode' . $index] = $fobPostalCode;
            $insertParams['priceType' . $index] = $priceType;
        }

        $productConfigStatement = $pdo->prepare($insertStatement);
        $productConfigStatement->execute($insertParams);

    } catch(Exeption $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

The $productConfigArray is structured like this:

```
       Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0011-02
                [1] => 0011-02BK
                [2] => USD
                [3] => 15068
                [4] => 15068
                [5] => Net
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0011-05
                [1] => 0011-05BK
                [2] => USD
                [3] => 15068
                [4] => 15068
                [5] => Net
            )
      )
```

The completed $insertStatement (after foreach):

```
"INSERT INTO productconfigTEST (productid, partid, currency, fobid, fobpostalcode, pricetype, configtype) VALUES (:productId0, :partId0, :currency0, :fobId0, :fobPostalCode0, :priceType0) (:productId1, :partId1, :currency1, :fobId1, :fobPostalCode1, :priceType1)"
```

The completed $insertParams:

```
Array ( [productId0] => 0011-02 [partId0] => 0011-02BK [currency0] => USD [fobId0] => 15068 [fobPostalCode0] => 15068 [priceType0] => Net [productId1] => 0011-05 [partId1] => 0011-05BK [currency1] => USD [fobId1] => 15068 [fobPostalCode1] => 15068 [priceType1] => Net )
```

Comment: If you don't see errors then the first step is to ensure they've definitely been enabled... https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Where is `$pdo` defined.

Comment: I agree with @ADyson. To easily confirm this - intentionally invoke a query you know is invalid (e.g. `this_is_intentionally_not_actually_an_sql_query`) and make sure you get and see a proper error.

Comment: $pdo is defiled in the file that contains the insertBatch function. My pdo is is defined like so $pdo = new PDO($_SERVER['AWSPDO'], $_SERVER['AWSUSER'], $_SERVER['AWSPASS']);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: $pdo was  not defined! That was the problem! Now I am at least getting errors. Thank you all very much!